# Generating a unique integer(4 bytes or 8 bytes) for a character string

Tags: c

If I have a list of strings made up of the characters a-z and "." (i.e total 27 characters) and each string can have maximum size 256 bytes, can I have a hash function which would have 0 collisions (practically, not theoretically)? Perfect hash functions won't work here as the string is not just read-only.

I do know that it's not possible to generate a hash function with 0 collisions, I'm interested in a practical solution.

I can use `md5sum` but that generates a 16 byte integer. I want just 4 bytes or max 8 bytes.

Comment: Since 2^64 is less than 27^256, you *cannot* have a hash function that *practically* has no collisions. Do you need randomness in your hash function, though?

Answer (score 3):

One solution: Just use a known hash function like MD5, and use the lowermost 4 or 8 bytes.

Comment: Actually it does not matter whether lowest or highest or middle or which. E.g. git uses the initial part of the hexadecimal representation of the SHA1 hash which, if the hash is actually written as number, would be the high part.

Comment: @Jan: Yeah it shouldn't matter for something good like SHA/MD5/etc... hence why I said *one* and not *the* solution. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Other people suggested the correct solution (use a hash sum) already, but if you're really interested in having as few collisions as possible, here are two thoughts to consider the problem in a larger scale:

1. In case you hold some (or all) of the strings which you want to generate IDs for in memory, you could use the memory address at which the string is stored as the ID. Assuming that changing the string in-place is okay, this ID would even remain stable as the string is changed.
2. It might be practical to use some simple compression system (e.g. [miniLZO](http://www.oberhumer.com/opensource/lzo/#minilzo)) to compress the strings in your list to some internal representation. You might end up with much less data to hash, so a simpler hash function might be possible. Of course, computing the hash is more expensive this way, but you might be able to avoid collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Some sort of checksum or hash *is* the correct answer.

You are right that you cannot avoid collisions. But if you shorten your checksum or hash to only 4 bytes, then the frequency of collisions will increase substantially.

If that's okay, you might check out something like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function to find one you feel comfortable with.

Comment: Git uses SHA1 hash to identify all objects and shortens them to unique prefix. 7 hexadecimal digits are enough most of the time, which is 3.5 bytes, so 4 bytes will probably do fine in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is limited, you can use that to guide the hashing.

Assuming the string is nul-terminated ASCII, you could start by mapping to a small integer.

```
char *charset = "abcdefghijklm"
                "nopqrstuvwxyz.";
int c = strchr(charset, *s++) - charset;
```

Then, treat each value as a base-27 radix number. Decode by multiplying the sum by 27 before adding in the 0-26 "unit" from the current character. You mention a maximum length. I'm guessing that means the strings are stored in fixed-length arrays. If this is so and the arrays are not just nul-terminated but nul-padded. then you can decode the arrays backwards to put the significant differences in least-significant "positions" of the base-27 number. But if the size is just a generous over-estimate and most strings are expected to be much shorter, then it's probably better to scan forwards and terminate on nul.

```
int sum;
sum *= 27;
sum += c;
```

Comment: 27**256 is rather larger than 64 bits ... your algorithm essentially ignores all but the first 14 bytes.

Comment: @Jim, Rats! You're right. Perhaps some kind of circular shift would be better than multiplying.